# Counter loop piped to grep seems unexpectedly random

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pipe, sh

Experiment to  make **grep** stop a **while** loop at **5** iterations, so that */tmp/foo* should only be **5** lines long:

```
n=1
while [ $n -le 2000 ]
do
    echo $n
    n=$(( $n + 1 ))
done | tee /tmp/foo | grep -q ^5
```

Check count:

```
wc -l < /tmp/foo
```

Outputs:

```
34
```

Repeated runs of the above return *different* numbers most every time, but it's not very random -- running the above 5000 times in **bash** results in about 1500 **9**s for example, running it 5000 times in **dash** results in 157 **106**s.

These results seem more interesting than the initial experiment.  What's happening in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipes are asynchronous. While `tee` will exit the first time it tries to write to its end of the pipe after `grep` exits and closes its end, there is no way to know how many lines `tee` will write *before* `grep` actually does so. It's entirely up to the OS scheduler.

Comment: So there's a lag between pipes, of uncertain duration.  The `grep` exit signal hops back at irregular intervals, tags each pipe member, and thus explains those irregular counter numbers.  Based on which, a simpler demo:  `seq 200000 | tee /tmp/foo | head -n 1 ; wc -l < /tmp/foo`, which outputs a `1`, then a number like `6775` or `10725`, which reflects how long it took for `seq` to get the exit signal from `head`.  It also explains why I couldn't duplicate the OP loop using `seq 2000` -- `seq` was too _fast_, reaching 2000 before the close signal from `grep` could touch it.

Comment: Right. The actual sequence might be this:  `head -1` exits, closing its end of the pipe with `tee`. When `tee` tries to write to the closed pipe, it gets `SIGPIPE` and exits, closing its end of the pipe with `seq`. If `seq` hasn't already exited naturally, it will get a `SIGPIPE` of its own when it tries to write to its own pipe.

Comment: So for `foo1 | foo2 | foo3 | foo4 | foo5 | ... foo_n_`, the sum of all the consecutive SIGPIPE closures from *foo2* to *foo_n_* is the minimum time it takes for *foo1*  to close.

Comment: Assuming none of the commands exit for reasons other than receiving `SIGPIPE`, yes.